# implementing a tree and breadth search with generics

Tags: java, generics, breadth-first-search

I dont have much experience with generics at all and am trying to get the hang of using them. After getting this to work with integers im trying to get it to work using generics but i keep getting the following error

required: genericTree
   found: int
   reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to genericTree by method invocation      conversion
   where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class genericTree
    genericTree.java:83: error: method add in class genericTree cannot be applied to     given types;

I get what its telling me but im not sure how to fix it. ive been trying different approaches but nothing seems to work for me.

heres my full code:

```
import java.util.*;

class genericTree<T>{

    private Node root;
    public List <genericTree<T>> list;

    private class Node
    {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    T data;

            Node(T newData)
            {
                    left = null;
                    right = null;
                    data = newData;
            }
    }

    genericTree()
    {
            root = null;
    }

    public boolean breadthSearch(genericTree<T> searchValue)
    {
    Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>() ;
            if (this.root == null)
                   return false;
    queue.clear();
    queue.add(root);
 while(!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        Node node = queue.remove();
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");

                    if(node.data == searchValue)
                            return true;
                    if(node.left != null)
                            queue.add(node.left);
                    if(node.right != null)
                            queue.add(node.right);
    }
     return false;
    }


    public void add(genericTree<T> data)
    {
      list.add(data);
    }

    public void display()
    {
            display(root);
    }

    private void display(Node node)
    {
            if(node==null)
                    return;
            display(node.left);
            System.out.println(node.data + " ");
            display(node.right);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       

    genericTree bst = new genericTree();
    bst.add(10);
    bst.add(5);
    bst.add(6);             
    bst.add(13);
    bst.add(15);
    bst.add(8);
    bst.add(14);
    bst.add(7);
    bst.add(12);
    bst.add(4);
    bst.breadthSearch(6);
    }
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: try `genericTree<int> bst = new genericTree<int>();`

Comment: What you need is - `genericTree<Integer> bst = new genericTree<Integer>();`.

Comment: that returns all the same errors with required: genericTree<Integer> found: int ?

Answer (score 0):

IT looks like you intended the following

```
public boolean breadthSearch(genericTree<T> searchValue)
```

to be this

```
public boolean breadthSearch(T searchValue)
```

You might also want to make sure that your `genericTree<T>` is a `genericTree<int>`

```
genericTree<int> bst = new genericTree<int>();
```

Comment: while it takes away most of my errors, now that line returns an error that says
 required: reference 
found: int